# Change part of an adserver tag with javasript

Tags: javascript

I insert **ads** on my website from a local adserver with the following code:

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="XX" data-revive-id="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"></ins>
<script async src="//www.website.com/adserver/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

I also use a **cookie-bar** on this website. I can check if a user has agreed to use cookies with this Javascript-code:

```
<script>
if (Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed()) {... user has agreed, do something ...}
</script>
```

Now I want to do the following:
The **"data-revive-zoneid"** from the ad tag should be

- "1" if the user has not agreed to cookies => *if (!Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed())*
- "2" if the user has agreed to cookies => *if (Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed())*

How can I change the adserver code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also create script tag dynamically after changing `data-revive-zoneid`

```
    function setZoneId(value) {
      document.querySelector("ins").setAttribute("data-revive-zoneid", value);

      const script = document.createElement("script);
      script.src = '//www.website.com/adserver/www/delivery/asyncjs.php';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    if (Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed()) {
      setZoneId(2);
    }
    else {
      setZoneId(1);
    }
```